# Populating sentences from large corpus table

Tags: mysql, corpus

I have five tables containing lexical data. I want to display sentences from corpus to the given Icelandic lemma (including all word forms). Using following approach, it takes 2 seconds to find 5 sentences. I am looking for a solution that can display all sentences available.

**The expected result:**

The list of sentences that contain all word forms of given lemma specified in the query.

**Current result:**

Current results returns only the sentences that match the word with the keyword in basic form:

```
 word_form  w_id    s_id    pos     sentence
 hest   11484   794930  1   Sentence 1. .....
 hest   11484   795623  12  Sentence 2 .....
```

Expected result:

```
 word_form  w_id    s_id    pos     sentence
 hest   11484   794930  1   Sentence 1. .....
 hest   11484   795623  12  Sentence 2 .....
 ...
 hestur ..   ..   ..  Sentence 13.
 hestur ..    ..  .. Sentence 14.
 ...
 hesti ..  ..  .. Sentence 21.
 ...
```

Proposed query with changes, but ends with error.

```
SELECT w0.keyword, w.word_form, w3.w_id, w4.s_id, w4.pos, s.sentence 
FROM `1_headword` w0
INNER JOIN `2_wordform` w ON w.keyword = w0.keyword
INNER JOIN `3_words` w3 ON w3.word = w.word_form
INNER JOIN `4_inv_w` w4 ON w4.w_id = w3.w_id 
INNER JOIN `5_sentences` s 
ON s.s_id = w4.s_id WHERE w0.keyword like 'hestur' group by w4.s_id
```

*Notes:*
Keyword is one, the basic form - in this case "hestur". The word forms are in this case - "hest", "hesti", "hestar" (see the Insert table) etc.
In other words, the query should take all wordform of given lemma and match it sentences in which the wordforms occur.

**Update II.**
Few observation. 
1.The following simplified query to receive w_id for all word forms returns rows with repeated w_id of the first word form.
2. The word forms can have several rows in `3_words` table.

```
   SELECT w.keyword, w.word_form, w3.w_id FROM `2_wordform1` w 
   JOIN `3_words` w3 
   ON w3.word = w.keyword and w3.gram = w.gram 
   WHERE w.keyword like 'tala' and w.gram = 'f'
```

Rows

```
    tala    tala    8809
    tala    tala    89664
    tala    tala    97991
    Tala    Tala    8809
    Tala    Tala    89664
    Tala    Tala    97991
    tala    tölur   8809
    tala    tölur   89664
    tala    tölur   97991
```

**Tables and data**

table - headwords, 70000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `1_headword` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_icelandic_ci NOT NULL,
  `num_keyword` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gram` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=55328 ;
ALTER TABLE `1_headword`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `keyword` (`keyword`);
```

table - word forms - 700 000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `2_wordform` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_icelandic_ci NOT NULL,
  `num_keyword` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `word_form` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_icelandic_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=678480 ;
ALTER TABLE `2_wordform`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `word_form` (`word_form`);
```

table - word forms tagged from corpus with w_id (word id), 1 million of rows

```
CREATE TABLE `3_words` (
  `w_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `gram` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `freq` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`w_id`),
  KEY `word` (`word`),
  KEY `w_id` (`w_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=800468 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table - w_id (word id) connected to s_id (sentence id), word can be found in several sentences, plus position in the sentence, 22 millions of rows

```
CREATE TABLE `4_inv_w` (
  `w_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `s_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pos` mediumint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `w_id` (`w_id`),
  KEY `s_id` (`s_id`),
  KEY `w_s` (`w_id`,`s_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table - s_id (sentence id) with sentence, 1 million of rows

```
CREATE TABLE `5_sentences` (
  `s_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sentence` text,
  KEY `s_id` (`s_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=999953 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Process

select all word forms of given lemma f.e "hestur" (horse in English)

```
SELECT `word_form` FROM `2_wordform` WHERE `keyword` like 'hestur'
```

result consist from 16 to 50 results, now cycle the result as f.e. with accusative "hest" of "hestur"

```
SELECT `w_id` FROM `3_words` WHERE `word` like 'hest'
```

the result can contain several w_id, f.e. with '10138'

```
SELECT `s_id`, `pos` FROM `4_inv_w` WHERE `w_id` = '10138' group by `s_id`
```

the result can contain several sentences, to display f.e. sentence '7201'

```
SELECT `sentence` FROM `5_sentences` WHERE `s_id` = '7201'
```

**Update**
    INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42490, 'hestur', 0, 'hest');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42498, 'hestur', 0, 'hesta');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42501, 'hestur', 0, 'hestana');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42503, 'hestur', 0, 'hestanna');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42497, 'hestur', 0, 'hestar');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42500, 'hestur', 0, 'hestarnir');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42491, 'hestur', 0, 'hesti');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42494, 'hestur', 0, 'hestinn');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42495, 'hestur', 0, 'hestinum');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42492, 'hestur', 0, 'hests');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42496, 'hestur', 0, 'hestsins');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42499, 'hestur', 0, 'hestum');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42502, 'hestur', 0, 'hestunum');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42489, 'hestur', 0, 'hestur');
INSERT INTO `2_wordform` (`id`, `keyword`, `num_keyword`, `word_form`) VALUES(42493, 'hestur', 0, 'hesturinn');

INSERT INTO `3_words` (`w_id`, `word`, `gram`, `freq`) VALUES
(11484, 'hestur', 'nken', 122),
(60681, 'Hestur', 'nken', 15),
(484318, 'HESTUR', 'nken', 1),
(491111, 'Hestur', 'nken-s', 1);

INSERT INTO `3_words` (`w_id`, `word`, `gram`, `freq`) VALUES
(10138, 'hest', 'nkeo', 141),
(159967, 'Hest', 'nkeo', 4),
(491114, 'Hest', 'ssm', 1);

INSERT INTO `4_inv_w` (`w_id`, `s_id`, `pos`) VALUES
(11484, 2671, 4),
(11484, 22522, 7),
(11484, 30169, 8),
(11484, 32487, 4),
(11484, 33841, 9),
(11484, 38116, 5),
(11484, 40450, 6),
(11484, 42741, 32),
(11484, 45789, 10),
(11484, 58998, 3),
(11484, 74343, 4),
(11484, 76001, 3),
(11484, 99014, 9),
(11484, 99688, 6),
(11484, 109849, 21),
(11484, 119708, 21),
(11484, 131353, 34),
(11484, 147820, 6),
(11484, 148326, 25),
(11484, 160475, 40),
(11484, 167227, 2),
(11484, 170401, 3),
(11484, 178416, 18),
(11484, 197295, 12),
(11484, 197295, 6),
(11484, 198420, 19),
(11484, 203446, 28),
(11484, 204448, 1),
(11484, 215402, 1),
(11484, 237323, 4),
(11484, 249282, 4),
(11484, 263949, 1),
(11484, 263949, 22),
(11484, 266489, 27),
(11484, 270540, 5),
(11484, 272543, 5),
(11484, 272560, 1),
(11484, 272560, 8),
(11484, 282170, 20),
(11484, 284407, 26),
(11484, 290524, 6),
(11484, 291438, 10),
(11484, 293344, 6),
(11484, 294034, 49),
(11484, 317007, 7),
(11484, 325049, 22),
(11484, 328392, 14),
(11484, 368188, 47),
(11484, 391892, 14),
(11484, 401157, 11),
(11484, 412656, 24),
(11484, 421635, 17),
(11484, 439320, 3),
(11484, 467063, 5),
(11484, 469324, 23),
(11484, 477392, 2),
(11484, 480318, 4),
(11484, 487883, 1),
(11484, 490577, 42),
(11484, 499783, 9),
(11484, 500405, 23),
(11484, 501118, 15),
(11484, 527227, 3),
(11484, 539686, 25),
(11484, 543056, 9),
(11484, 544261, 3),
(11484, 547700, 20),
(11484, 555638, 19),
(11484, 570234, 2),
(11484, 592710, 2),
(11484, 616662, 1),
(11484, 619011, 16),
(11484, 632123, 2),
(11484, 633124, 2),
(11484, 636792, 8),
(11484, 636792, 3),
(11484, 646603, 17),
(11484, 664738, 4),
(11484, 670017, 4),
(11484, 685997, 4),
(11484, 686202, 1),
(11484, 691794, 12),
(11484, 698341, 2),
(11484, 715281, 3),
(11484, 715984, 37),
(11484, 716970, 10),
(11484, 716970, 4),
(11484, 752605, 36),
(11484, 756660, 19),
(11484, 760277, 3),
(11484, 776593, 3),
(11484, 785701, 24),
(11484, 789099, 3),
(11484, 794930, 1),
(11484, 795623, 12),
(11484, 802997, 6),
(11484, 812806, 6),
(11484, 814046, 21),
(11484, 820178, 6),
(11484, 823173, 22),
(11484, 843094, 3),
(11484, 844156, 1),
(11484, 844736, 24),
(11484, 853350, 18),
(11484, 869322, 3),
(11484, 885176, 2),
(11484, 899545, 22),
(11484, 904086, 16),
(11484, 907863, 9),
(11484, 909396, 9),
(11484, 912876, 3),
(11484, 919994, 4),
(11484, 927840, 24),
(11484, 927840, 5),
(11484, 934220, 40),
(11484, 936941, 11),
(11484, 952837, 13),
(11484, 969201, 11),
(11484, 970240, 1),
(11484, 970836, 19),
(11484, 972107, 1),
(11484, 990474, 6);

INSERT INTO `4_inv_w` (`w_id`, `s_id`, `pos`) VALUES
(10138, 7201, 27),
(10138, 18772, 3),
(10138, 30001, 6),
(10138, 42089, 4),
(10138, 42089, 14),
(10138, 42234, 4),
(10138, 49383, 5),
(10138, 54795, 18),
(10138, 57564, 23),
(10138, 88542, 7),
(10138, 93027, 10),
(10138, 101097, 21),
(10138, 134312, 12),
(10138, 139116, 33),
(10138, 139522, 6),
(10138, 159109, 7),
(10138, 159109, 16),
(10138, 161497, 21),
(10138, 163948, 2),
(10138, 165301, 20),
(10138, 166478, 21),
(10138, 183452, 6),
(10138, 184390, 20),
(10138, 189930, 25),
(10138, 201629, 9),
(10138, 204590, 4),
(10138, 211374, 5),
(10138, 216483, 14),
(10138, 223617, 5),
(10138, 233652, 12),
(10138, 236571, 11),
(10138, 241302, 8),
(10138, 246485, 10),
(10138, 256910, 16),
(10138, 262349, 3),
(10138, 262925, 5),
(10138, 267047, 28),
(10138, 291988, 18),
(10138, 292680, 22),
(10138, 294814, 32),
(10138, 326917, 6),
(10138, 330019, 12),
(10138, 333411, 35),
(10138, 337880, 5),
(10138, 342003, 13),
(10138, 355325, 12),
(10138, 356409, 13),
(10138, 363795, 5),
(10138, 365735, 26),
(10138, 376570, 25),
(10138, 378214, 10),
(10138, 379159, 11),
(10138, 379236, 4),
(10138, 379533, 2),
(10138, 388753, 8),
(10138, 420633, 18),
(10138, 433121, 5),
(10138, 434645, 10),
(10138, 435895, 3),
(10138, 455575, 5),
(10138, 461900, 23),
(10138, 464040, 6),
(10138, 466657, 6),
(10138, 469848, 11),
(10138, 475569, 17),
(10138, 482701, 41),
(10138, 527708, 29),
(10138, 527708, 16),
(10138, 529426, 7),
(10138, 530753, 10),
(10138, 538071, 27),
(10138, 542685, 10),
(10138, 553742, 22),
(10138, 553742, 13),
(10138, 557216, 4),
(10138, 563747, 9),
(10138, 564716, 4),
(10138, 569146, 7),
(10138, 578368, 3),
(10138, 581713, 9),
(10138, 595890, 9),
(10138, 599015, 5),
(10138, 608570, 30),
(10138, 610218, 11),
(10138, 610218, 2),
(10138, 612099, 9),
(10138, 612568, 14),
(10138, 612894, 9),
(10138, 615361, 19),
(10138, 618001, 14),
(10138, 624969, 7),
(10138, 628252, 16),
(10138, 628635, 12),
(10138, 635977, 10),
(10138, 643675, 8),
(10138, 650487, 9),
(10138, 651489, 3),
(10138, 657552, 18),
(10138, 672884, 12),
(10138, 677130, 2),
(10138, 678841, 7),
(10138, 678841, 26),
(10138, 682904, 4),
(10138, 691251, 19),
(10138, 706325, 9),
(10138, 714680, 45),
(10138, 717460, 5),
(10138, 717489, 11),
(10138, 722393, 5),
(10138, 729972, 12),
(10138, 735745, 12),
(10138, 738334, 7),
(10138, 740791, 21),
(10138, 775696, 8),
(10138, 776984, 16),
(10138, 786073, 31),
(10138, 793185, 17),
(10138, 821475, 4),
(10138, 835234, 7),
(10138, 842713, 3),
(10138, 842730, 8),
(10138, 847372, 9),
(10138, 849612, 20),
(10138, 861768, 26),
(10138, 864231, 6),
(10138, 865927, 7),
(10138, 873939, 7),
(10138, 883591, 29),
(10138, 884260, 19),
(10138, 894952, 17),
(10138, 898453, 19),
(10138, 899290, 4),
(10138, 909225, 29),
(10138, 910173, 4),
(10138, 922447, 2),
(10138, 939319, 2),
(10138, 956278, 4),
(10138, 967342, 18),
(10138, 977090, 3),
(10138, 991346, 31),
(10138, 991346, 40);

INSERT INTO `5_sentences` (`s_id`, `sentence`) VALUES
(2671, 'Hrímnir|nken-s frá|aþ Hrafnagili|nkeþ-s Glæsilegasti|lkenve hestur|nken aldar|nvee !|!');

INSERT INTO `5_sentences` (`s_id`, `sentence`) VALUES
(7201, 'Hann|fpken heilsar|sfg3en öllum|fokfþ nema|c Braga|nkeþ-s sem|ct nú|aa dregur|sfg3en í|ao land|nheo og|c vill|sfg3en friðmælast|snm við|ao Loka|nkeo-s með|aþ loforði|nheþ um|ao góðar|lvfosf gjafir|nvfo ,|, sverð|nhfo ,|, hest|nkeo og|c hring|nkeo en|c hann|fpken svarar|sfg3en bara|aa með|aþ illu|lheþsf .|.');

Comment: it is not clear how `2_wordform` relates to `3_words`. It seem nothing changes if you exclude `2_wordform` from the sequence

Comment: I see, 2_wordform finds from 16 to 50 results. The next step runs on all those results. Wordform 'hest' was for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sample of data would be very helpful together with expected result.

So far you can start form this attempt:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7110ef/4

```
SELECT w.word_form,
       w3.w_id,
       w4.s_id,
       w4.pos,
       s.sentence
FROM `2_wordform` w 
INNER JOIN `3_words` w3
ON w3.`word` = w.keyword
INNER JOIN `4_inv_w`  w4
ON w4.w_id = w3.w_id
INNER JOIN `5_sentences` s
ON s.s_id = w4.s_id
WHERE w.keyword like '%hestur%'
```

if you need only sentence you can:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.sentence
FROM `2_wordform` w 
INNER JOIN `3_words` w3
ON w3.`word` = w.keyword
INNER JOIN `4_inv_w`  w4
ON w4.w_id = w3.w_id
INNER JOIN `5_sentences` s
ON s.s_id = w4.s_id
WHERE w.keyword like '%hestur%'
```

Comment: I will update the question and add data regarding the word "hestur".

Comment: So check my query, and say what do you need as expected result?

Comment: Ok, I will test your query on real data, it seems very fast. The expected result is list of sentences in which the given lemma (and its wordforms) is displayed.

Comment: Thank you! You can have a look at the usage in [hvalur dictionary](http://www.hvalur.org/search.php?list_kind=alpha&d_h=%C3%BEakka&d_h_n=0). It regards the Text from Leipzig Corpora Collection.

Comment: I have realized that `w3.word = w.keyword` is comparing Wordforms from table `w3` with Basicform from `w`, so that only sentences with basic form are shown. If I change condition to  `w3.word = w.word_form`, I receive error `Lost connection..`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Just add your current result set and "correct" - your expectations about what do you prefer to get instead?